# SSDT - Schema compare drops old sprocs, publish does not

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare

I'm using database projects in Visual Studio 2015.  I've noticed that if I remove a sproc from the project and then generate a publish script there is nothing in the script that will dump the old sproc.  However, if I remove a sproc and use schema compare/update the sproc will be dumped.

Can anyone help me understand this behavior?  I want to generate a publish script to review the changes which are about to be made before publishing them so I like to generate a script.  However I don't want to have to both do a schema compare/update and publish every time I'm pushing changes out.

Thank you.

Comment: At a guess you are not comparing to the correct database, can you give more information about your process please?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to enable "Drop objects in target but not in source" in the Publish settings.

[image]